# transaction not upgrading to distributed transaction

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have controller code similar to the following (anonymized here). I expect an exception to be thrown due to the lack of distributed transaction support in EF Core 6, and I expect the code to attempt to upgrade the transaction to a distributed transaction due to using two different `DbConnection`s and two different `DbContext`s within the same transaction. I debugged and verified that the two different connections have different process IDs and so it does not seem to be related to connection pooling. Why does this code seem to work?

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Npgsql;

namespace Controllers.Test;

[Route("test")]
public sealed class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IHostEnvironment _host;

    public TestController(
        IConfiguration configuration,
        IHostEnvironment host)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _host = host;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public void Get()
    {
        using var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(
            TransactionScopeOption.Required,
            new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) },
            TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);

        var fooConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("foo")!;
        var barConnectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString("bar")!;

        using var fooConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(fooConnectionString);
        using var barConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(barConnectionString);
        
        fooConnection.Open();
        barConnection.Open();

        using var fooDbContext = new FooDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FooDbContext>()
            .UseNpgsql(fooConnection, o => o.UseNodaTime())
            .Options);
        using var barDbContext = new BarDbContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BarDbContext>()
            .UseNpgsql(barConnection, o => o.UseNodaTime())
            .Options);

        var foo = fooDbContext.Foos.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
        foo.SequenceNumber++;
        fooDbContext.SaveChanges();

        var bar = barDbContext.Bars.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
        bar.SequenceNumber++;
        barDbContext.SaveChanges();

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

.NET Core 6

Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL version 6.0.7

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore version 6.0.8

Answer (score 1):

What version of .Net Core are you running? Distributed transactions were supported on Windows with .Net Core 7. If you build against .Net Core 6 you may see the expected exception. It is possible that Npgsql is not fully supporting them and ignoring or re-using the connection, you might try:

```
    var foo = fooDbContext.Foos.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
    foo.SequenceNumber++;
    var bar = barDbContext.Bars.OrderBy(x => x.Id).First();
    bar.SequenceNumber++;

    fooDbContext.SaveChanges();
    barDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

From the Npgsql doco: (https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html)

> While Npgsql partially supports this mechanism, it does not implement the recovery parts of the distributed transaction, because of some design issues with .NET's support. While distributed transactions may work for you, it is discouraged to fully rely on them with Npgsql.

Comment: edited the end of the question to specify that this is on .NET Core 6

Comment: I suspect then that Npgsql is may be ignoring the transaction scope. If you do a rollback on the scope does it revert the changes? Are your two connection strings pointing at completely separate database instances? Typically SO questions are "why isn't this working?" rather than "why is this working when it shouldn't?" :)

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time to respond to my question :)

Npgsql seems to be respecting the `TransactionScope`, as if I omit the call to `Complete()` then the changes are are not persisted to the DB.  The two connection strings are the same except that they specify a different database name on the same Postgres server. I know that it's a weird question but I'm worried that there may be subtle issues with this since it doesn't *seem* like it should work at all, and I would also just like to have a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: Npgsql certainly does not ignore the transaction scope. As written above, distributed transactions are only supported on .NET 7.0 and above, and only on Windows.